# ScriptError: Not authorized to send Apple events to Terminal when running code on Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

Whenever I try to debug some C# code in Visual Studio I keep getting this error code: **Debugger operation failed** - *ScriptError: Not authorized to send Apple events to Terminal.*

The project is created as   a C# template.

I have tried googling the error message but I have not found anything of value. I have attached screenshots of the code and the error.

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Debugger operation failed**

ScriptError: Not authorized to send Apple events to Terminal.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbIqw.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAQ7r.png)

Comment: Please post code and error message, not screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with you when i upgraded to mojave..
according to this link [macOS Mojave, Automator “Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299066/macos-mojave-automator-not-authorized-to-send-apple-events-to-system-events) you need to checklist terminal in System -> Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Automation for Visual Studio..

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks. The answer at the link works. Please update your answer though; the setting is at System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Automation not the path you have.

Comment: thank you for your correction @GrantVS.. i updated the answer