# Error: Command failed: osascript -e tell app "System Events" to count processes whose name is "Simulator" (-1743)

Tags: applescript, expo

after I run expo start

the web console open successfully, but the iOS simulator can't work as usual

Error installing or running app. Error: Command failed: osascript -e tell app "System Events" to count processes whose name is "Simulator"
28:69: execution error: 未獲授權傳送 Apple Event 給「System Events」。 (-1743)

How can I fix this?

React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.3
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 38.77 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.npm-global/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz => 0.57.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 9):

I used this link to help me figure it out: [macOS Mojave, Automator “Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299066/macos-mojave-automator-not-authorized-to-send-apple-events-to-system-events) 32

I went to

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Automation > Privacy:
and made sure 'System Events' was checked under xcode

There were others suggesting to restart my mac so that may help as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it worked, although it was iTerm that needed System Events privilage for me  (as run from the terminal)

Comment: Thank you both, what I did was follow William's instruction and give the permission to iTerm, then restart iTerm and it solved the problem